# WC Сделать купон уникальным для каждого пользователя

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нашел код на автоматическое создание купона при регистрации. Настроил под себя как мне нужно.

```
add_action('user_register', 'creat_coupon_for_new_user', 10, 1);

function creat_coupon_for_new_user($user_id) {

$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res1 = "";
$res2 = "";
$res3 = "";
$res4 = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $res1 .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $res2 .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $res3 .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $res4 .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}

$coupon_code = $res1.'-'.$res2.'-'.$res3.'-'.$res4;
$amount = '70';
$discount_type = 'percent';
$description = __('Тут будет описание купона');

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_excerpt' => $description,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post($coupon);

update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type);
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount);
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '26');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '47, 49, 45');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit_per_user', '1');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', strtotime("+6 months"));
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, '_is_coupon_cashback', 'yes');
update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'minimum_amount', '5000');
}
```

Но есть одно но. Не знаю как привязать купон к одному пользователю, т.е. чтоб купон был уникальным для каждого пользователя. Как такое реализовать?

Потому что я вывожу список купонов на странице Мой аккаунт, и если люди будут регистрироваться то все созданные купоны будут выводится там. Что мне делать?

Вот код который выводит купоны на странице Мой аккаунт:

```
$couponargs = array(
'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
'post__in' => $couponarrayfinal,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => '-1'); // Create a new query to run thruogh the arguments
$coupons = get_posts($couponargs); // Create a second loop linked to that query

<div class="wt-mycoupons">
<div class="mycoupons-title">Мои купоны <sub style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;">(нажми на промо-код чтобы скопировать его)</sub></div>
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

        $coupon_item = new WC_Coupon( $coupon->ID );
        $expires = $coupon_item->get_date_expires();
        $amount_coupon = $coupon_item->get_amount();
        $used_count = $coupon_item->get_usage_count();
        $used_count_limit = $coupon_item->get_usage_limit_per_user();
        $math_count_limit = $used_count_limit - $used_count;

        if ( $used_count >= $used_count_limit && $used_count_limit > 0  ) {
            echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon used' >";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon' >";
        }
        echo "<div class='coupon-top'>";
        echo "<div class='coupon-info'>";
        echo "<div class='code-coupon' id='$coupon->ID'>";
        echo "$coupon->post_title";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='desc-coupon'>";
        echo "$coupon->post_excerpt";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='coupon-amount'>";
        echo $amount_coupon;
        echo "%";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='coupon-bottom'>";
        echo "<div class='coupon-use'>";
        if ( $used_count >= $used_count_limit && $used_count_limit > 0 ) {
            echo "Купон исчерпан.";
        } else if ( $used_count_limit == 0) {
            echo "Купон не ограничен в использовании.";
        } else {
            echo "Еще можно использовать ";
            if ($math_count_limit == '1' || $math_count_limit == '5' || $math_count_limit == '6' || $math_count_limit == '7' || $math_count_limit == '8' || $math_count_limit == '9') {
                echo $math_count_limit;
                echo " раз.";
            } else if ($math_count_limit == '2' || $math_count_limit == '3' || $math_count_limit == '4') {
                echo $math_count_limit;
                echo " раза.";
            }
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='coupon-expiry__time'>";
        if ( $expires ) {
            $date_end = $expires->format('d.m.Y');
            $date = strtotime("$date_end");
            $remaining = $date - time();
            $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
            echo "Купон действует еще ";
            echo $days_remaining;
            echo " дн.";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";

    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал сам.

1.

```
'post_author' => $user_id,
```

2.

```
$userCouponID = $coupon->post_author;
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

3.

```
if ( $userCouponID == $user_id ) {}
```

Коротко, кто поймет, тому повезло.

Comment: Ну и правильно, нормальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо за похвалу)

Comment: Отметьте ответ как принятый, когда система позволит. Это поможет ориентироваться другим пользователям.

Comment: Жду этого, систем пишет что смогу уже завтра.